# Problems in creating an add_employee() function in my database

Tags: python-3.x, database, list

I am writing code for my class, and I have run into a problem. We are learning about creating and manipulating a database using delimited file. I have hit a wall with trying to add an employee to my imaginary company.

Here is the function in question:

```
def add_employee(employees):
    import validations
    id = validations.generate_next_id_multi(employees)
    fname = validations.validate_first_name()
    lname = validations.validate_last_name()
    name = fname + ' ' + lname
    dept = validations.validate_emp_dept()
    salary = validations.validate_emp_salary()
    for employee in employees:
      employee.append(id+';'+name+';'+dept+';'+salary+'\n')
    return employees
```

When I run the code, I am able to type in the inputs, but the list is not being written to the file after I append to the list. I have a list_to_file() function that works well, so the problem is not that. Here is the code that is causing the main issue:

```
def generate_next_id_multi(employees):
    for employee in employees:
      if len(employee) == 0:
        emp_id = '1001'
        return emp_id
    idslice = employees[0][::4]
    emp_id = int(max(idslice))
    new_id = str(emp_id+1)
    return new_id
```

I have tried to store `idslice = employees[::4][0]`, but I get ValueError, so clearly I am not understanding how to parse through a multilist in order to create the new employee.

An example of the file is:

```
1001;Hugh Mungus;HR;50020\n
1002;Kevin Hart;STND;100000\n
```

In the `file_to_list()` function I have successfully created a multidimensional list that separates each piece of information, so that is not an issue.

The main question is how to fix the `validations.generate_next_id_multi()` function?